# In spark streaming in integration with Kafka, why do completed executors wait for processing executors to complete it's batch

Tags: scala, apache-spark, kubernetes, spark-streaming

Let's say there are 8 executors for spark and 8 partitions in Kafka, and i start a spark streaming in which each executor picks up data from respective partition. (Running in kubernetes)

Now what is happening is let's say in first batch with maxRatePerPartition as 15000, let's say 5 of 8 executors processed data ( which includes reading MySQL db) in 5 minutes(due to cache) and remaining 3 of 8 executors take 45minutes(maybe due to reading from db and no data in cache)
My issue is the 5 executors that read from each of its own partitions from Kafka in 5 minutes they don't pick up next batch and just be idle and not pickup any active tasks either until the remaining 3 executors finish their processing, and i see in spark ui that executors only those 3 have 1 active task each and remaining 5 have 0 active task.

Can we make it such a way that 5 executors just continue to pick up there next batch and start processing and not make them wait for those 3 executors instead

I am expecting if we can make them independent so that each executor just picks up load from it's own next batch from Kafka partition and not wait for other executors to complete current batch. Like create multiple active stages in streaming so that it run different batches at one's based on each executors